How to do EFA correctly using R studio?
I am currently a bit lost because of my Confirmatory Factor Analysis results. I compared a 2-factor solution (warmth and competence scales) with a 3-factor-solution (competence, sociability and morality scales), in order to decide which scales to use for my main analysis.
One model (3-factor-solution) showed a slightly better fit than the other one and the Cronbachs alpha indicated internal consistency, our CFAs showed however that both models had an almost not acceptable fit. Therefore I am trying to run an EFA but my code apparently doesn't work. I also want to allow for correlation between items.
Could you please help me out ? Its my first time doing this.
library(psych)
# Define item sets for each construct
items_warmth <- c("scm.1", "scm.2", "scm.3", "scm.4", "scm.5", "scm.6", "scm.7", "scm.8", "scm.9", "scm.10")
items_competence <- c("scm.11", "scm.12", "scm.13", "scm.14", "scm.15", "scm.16", "scm.17", "scm.18")
items_sociability <- c("scm.6", "scm.7", "scm.8", "scm.9", "scm.10")
items_morality <- c("scm.1", "scm.2", "scm.3", "scm.4", "scm.5")

# Perform exploratory factor analysis for the 2-factor model (warmth and competence)
efa_2factor <- fa(longdf[, c(items_warmth, items_competence)], nfactors = 2, rotate = "promax")

# Perform exploratory factor analysis for the 3-factor model (competence, sociability, morality)
efa_3factor <- fa(longdf[, c(items_competence, items_sociability, items_morality)], nfactors = 3, rotate = "promax")

BUT THEN HOW TO PROCEED ? EVERYTHING I TRIED DIDNT WORK ...
